# checked property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox

I need to check the property of a check box before submit and perform an error message before POST using jQuery.

For example, if no friends are checked, I'm trying to show an alert before sending data. 
My codes:

```
function send(friends)
{
 var data = {};
 data['url'] = $('#link').attr('src');
 val = [];
  $("input[name='friends']").each(function(i)
  {
    if(this.checked == true)
      val.push(this.value);
  });
  data['friends'] = val;
  $.post('send.php', data);
  $("#sentmsg").addClass("in").fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
  $("input[name='friends']").removeAttr("checked");
  $("#success").show();
}
```

not sure where i put this into code to work:

```
else if(this.checked == false)
{
    alert("no box ticked!");
}
```

Comment: "protip": `val = $('input[name=friends]:checked').map(function () { return this.value });` You also need to use the `success` callback of `$.post`, or of the promise-like object it returns, rather than just assuming success and showing `#success`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of `val` variable. But to find the values of the selected items use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
function send(friends) {
    var data = {};
    data['url'] = $('#link').attr('src');

    //use .map() to convert the dom reference to an array
    var val = $("input[name='friends']:checked").map(function (i) {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    if(!val.length){
        alert('friends not selected');
        return
    }

    data['friends'] = val;
    $.post('send.php', data);
    $("#sentmsg").addClass("in").fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    $("input[name='friends']").removeAttr("checked");
    $("#success").show();
}
```

Comment: How nice of you to downvote all other answers when posting yours...?

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness who said it your answer was downvoted

Comment: No one has downvoted anything? all help is appreciated to me. Arun's reply is exactly what i needed to figure out. Edit: it wont allow me upvote anything, i would upvote this if i could. thanks Arun.

Comment: Of course we got downvoted. We all stood at 1 before his post. Not that my life centers around getting points on stackoverflow just thought it was a bit childish.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness if you don't believe you can flag this answer and ask a moderator whether your answer was downvoted

Comment: Why would I flag your answer when it's correct? He can accept whichever he wishes...

Answer (score 0):

This could be an easier approach to checking if no one is checked...

```
var checked = $('input[name="friends"]:checked');
//number of checked boxes
var nr_checked = checked.length;
if (!nr_checked) {
    alert("no box ticked!");
} else {
   //Do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
if(val.length == 0){
    alert("no box ticked!");
}
```